# osx kernel debug cannot 'malloc_get_all_zones'

Tags: macos, debugging, kernel

I am doing some OSX kernel debugging with `lldb` and `KDK`.

When the kernel crash,I want to view the zones,and search the zones.
So I use:

```
(lldb) command script import lldb.macosx.heap
(lldb) cstr_refs CSTRING
```

This command is always working in Ring3 debugging, but when at kernel debugging, `lldb` give me an error:

```
error: error: use of undeclared identifier 'malloc_get_all_zones'
error: 1 errors parsing expression
```

The script `heap.py` is unusable in kernel?

How to search the kernel zones at this situation？

Answer (score 1):

Someone more familiar with kernel issues can maybe tell you how to get the information you want out of the kernel.  I can answer the part about "heap.py".  It is only meant to be used when debugging userland programs.  It relies on details of the userland malloc implementation, and it relies on being able to call functions in the debugee which is not currently possible when debugging the kernel.

Note, if you get the KDK so you have the dSYM for the mach kernel, it defines a bunch of commands that poke around in the kernel's data structures.  It may be one of them will tell you what you want to know.  Remember to run the lldb command:

```
(lldb) settings set target.load-script-from-symbol-file true
```

in order to allow lldb to read in the Python from the dSYM that defines all these macros.  Then running the lldb `help` command will show you all the kernel-specific commands.